# .profile in LXDE

Tags: debian, lxde, .profile

I recently install debian wheezy (7.5) from the netinst, without gnome3, then install LXDE with `sudo apt-get install task-lxde-desktop`. No trouble with this, LXDE works perfectly :)
I was trying to execute `xrandr` on my login when I met a behavior I don't understand.

Here is my `.profile` (I didn't modify it)

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

When I login from the xserver, the `~/bin` directory isn't add to `PATH`. When I login from tty[1-6], it's properly add to `PATH`.
I read the default shell for lxde is dash (and not bash), but I think `.profile` is compatible with dash, isn't it ?

Here is my final question : **Why my .profile isn't sourced when I log from the xserver ?**

Any help appreciated
Sorry for my poor english =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most probably the display manager. **XDM** and **lightdm** see themselves not as login shell and therefore do not source /etc/profile or ~/.profile.

Other display managers as **Slim**, **KDM** or **GDM** do source those files. I suggest you switch to one of them.

See also https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager

Comment: I waited for a long time, but I have an answer ! Thank you, I'm going to try Slim ;)